# invalid input syntax for type timestamp

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

While running the below code i get an error saying invalid input syntax for type timestamp from admission_datetime.

```
    UPDATE ccsm.stg_demographics_baseline
    SET xx_los_days =
    (CASE WHEN admission_datetime IS NULL OR 
    date_trunc('day',admission_datetime) = ''
    THEN NULL
    WHEN discharge_datetime IS NULL OR 
    date_trunc('day',discharge_datetime) = ''
    THEN date_diff('day', admission_datetime, CURRENT_DATE)
    ELSE
    date_diff('day', admission_datetime, discharge_datetime)
    END);
enter code here
```

Comment: admission_datetime is of type timestamp.
eg: 2016-06-22 19:10:25-07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`date_trunc` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

> The return value is of type timestamp or interval with all fields that are less significant than the selected one set to zero (or one, for day and month).

So you can not compare it with an empty string:

```
date_trunc('day', admission_datetime) = ''
```

The `invalid input syntax for type timestamp` error message concerns the empty string (`''`), not the `admission_datetime` column.

Furthermore, there is no `date_diff` function in PostgreSQL. Just subtract one `timestamp` from another and you will get an `interval` result:

```
SELECT timestamp '2001-09-29 03:00' - timestamp '2001-09-27 12:00'
```

You'll get

```
interval '1 day 15:00:00'
```

If you need the difference in *days*, try this:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', timestamp '2001-09-29 03:00' - timestamp '2001-09-27 12:00')
```

The result is `1`.

See [here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) for examples of `DATEDIFF`-like expressions in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You are right i just changed that to is null and it worked