# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "09/03/1943 01:00:00 MWT"

Tags: php, postgresql

I am inserting records from `table1.column1` to `table2.colum2`. Both the columns are of `timestampz` type.

Unfortunately, one record having value "1943-09-03 01:00:00-06" throws below error:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone:
>   "09/03/1943 01:00:00 MWT"

I can fix this by using `::TIMESTAMP`.

Can anyone tell me what is the right way to fix it and why it is happening only for the one record?

**Edit 1:**

Both the tables are on different databases. So I am selecting values from `Table1.column1` and then inserting into `Table2.column2` separately in a different database connection. I guess, PHP's core PostgreSQL functions converting value "1943-09-03 01:00:00-06" to string time "09/03/1943 01:00:00 MWT" and this string time throwing error while inserting.

I am actually trying to insert "09/03/1943 01:00:00 MWT" and not "1943-09-03 01:00:00-06".

Comment: Please specify what is wrong with the question. Just by downvoting won't resolve my concern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid input syntax for type timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598266/invalid-input-syntax-for-type-timestamp)

Comment: If you insert `"1943-09-03 01:00:00-06" ` it can work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d348b/1

Comment: @D-Shih - Thanks for help. Please check `Edit 1`. I am actually inserting "09/03/1943 01:00:00 MWT" and not "1943-09-03 01:00:00-06".

Comment: @aagjalpankaj I write an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `::TIMESTAMP` will use DB default time format, the format depend on your DB culture.

I would suggest you specify the `datetime` format of your string explicitly When you want to convert `string` to `DateTime` or timestamp

you can try to use [to_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) function and set string to `DateTime` format.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('09/03/1943 01:00:00 MWT', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/20455/0)**:

```
|         to_timestamp |
|----------------------|
| 1943-03-09T01:00:00Z |
```